# What's the Destination unreachable ICMP packet(ICMP payload the UDP) usage?

Tags: networking, wireshark, icmp

In my Mac(192.168.2.228), it will send ICMP packet to my house's router (192.168.2.1).
with the info `Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)`
[image]

and in the Wireshark packet detail panel, there displays the packet structure:

```
eth:ehtertype:ip:icmp:ip:udp
```

[image]

and more details:

the payload is `IP:UDP` (from router to mac), and you see the router port is `53`, it related to DNS.

[image]

[image]

[image]

and in my macOS, there is no application listening the port:

`$ netstat -an | grep 55166` get nothing.

---

What's the protocol use the packet? and what's the intension of the packet?

Comment: Src port is 53. It means DNS. DNS is udp. As i think, it is connecting via DNS

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ICMP is used to signal network layer (IP) or transport layer (TCP, UDP, ...) errors.

In this case, the ICMP sender `192.168.2.228` informs the initial sender `192.168.2.1` that a transport layer port cannot be reached. The ICMP payload contains parts of the problem packet with the network and transport layer headers. In your case that seems to have been a DNS reply.

Note that host configurations and issues are off-topic here, so we can't dive into the actual reason for the rejection.

Answer (score 0):

Your displaying packet is a message sent via ICMP.

the message means from router's DNS response to your mac unreachable.

```
192.168.2.1:53 -> 192.168.2.228:55166
```

You can check your firewall on your macOS, or use Wireshark to capture the while process.

set the filter in your Capture filter:

```
(udp) and (host 192.168.2.1) and (port 53)
```